# Generate random numbers without repetition while maintaining transition between pages

Tags: javascript, html

Help tell me how Numbers randomly without repetition while maintaining the transition between pages. Thank you in advance

```
    var da = randomInteger(1, 3);

    function randomInteger(min, max) {
        var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
        rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand; 
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome, can you please explain _while maintaining the transition between pages_ ?

Comment: Hi, saving variables between pages, that would be the number that was not repeated

Comment: You can use localStorage to store the last value.

Comment: Now it is clear how to store. how to make that they do not recur?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the previously drawn values. Then when you need another random value, repetitively use Math.random() until the value doesn't appear in your storage. Store and use a qualifying value.

Comment: Now it is clear how to store. how to make that they do not recur?

Comment: @Dada Do you want the value to differ only from the last draw, or from all previous draw? Either you will want to store all previously drawn values, then retrieve them as a set which you will verify does not contain the newly drawn value, or you will just store the previously drawn value and evaluate equality.

Comment: @AaronI want the new value to not repeat those which have already been

Comment: @Dada then store an array, and use Array.prototype.includes()